# Ansible: generate dynamic variables from group_vars

Tags: python, dns, ansible

I use Ansible to generate the configuration of a named server.

My objective is to generate DNS reverse zone files for each of my netowrks. In order to follow standards I must split my clasless zone in many classfull zones. For example, with 172.16.0.0/23 network I have to split it in two /24 reverse zones: 0.16.172.in-addr.arpa and 1.16.172.in-addr.arpa.

I have data about network in group_vars/all/networks.yaml:

```
  netX:                    
    subnet: 172.16.0.0   
    netmask: 255.255.254.0 
    netmask_short: 23      
    broadcast: 172.16.1.255
```

And I want to generate files from a template:

```
- name: Generate reverse files          
  template:                             
    src: reverse.j2                     
    dest: "/var/named/reverse.{{item['network_name']}}" 
    owner: root                         
    group: root                         
    mode: 0644                          
  with_items: <DYNAMIC_DATA_GENERATED_FROM_NETWORK_VARIABLES>
```

What's the best practice to generate data structure what I need in `with_items` ? I need to use a function which takes data from file `network.yaml` and produce an output like this:

```
[ {'network_name': 'netX', 
   'zone': '0.16.172.in-addr.arpa']},
  {'network_name': 'netX', 
   'zone': '1.16.172.in-addr.arpa']},]
```

Should I use a python script called in a previous task and store the result in a variable in order to use it in `with_items` ?

Comment: Perfect use case for custom filter plugin which takes `netX` structure as input and produces desired output.